# Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

How am i going to fix this? I downloaded the SDKs that i need but but the error does not go away.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkkhX.png)

Answer (score 0):

your need build tool 29.0.2.

[image]

for install =>

1.File>Setting>Appearavne & Behavior>System Setting>Android SDK.
2.go to tab SDK Tools
3. on check android SDK Tools X.X.X(Download)

[image]